# SelectableText has terrible performance on web

Tags: flutter

I don't understand why `SelectableText` leads to such a terrible performance on web(destkop) whereas with normal `Text` performance is perfectly fine.

The minimal, reproducable code example below consists of a `ListView.builder` with the `itemCount` being 16.000 and the `itemExtent` being 30. Each item is a Row with 16 `Text` widgets. If you run the code in release mode with `Text` widgets vertical scrolling works perfectly fine. However switching the `Text` widgets with `SelectableText` widgets leads vertical scrolling to lag in an unacceptable manner.

Code example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemExtent: 30,
          itemCount: 16000,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return const Row(
              children: [
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                Text("text"),
                //switch with SelectableText to notice lagging
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
                // SelectableText("text"),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is the text even selectable?  I'm having issues with text not being selectable on web in scroll views.  SelectionArea and SelectableText.

Comment: It should be selectable, well, assuming  you umcommented the commented part in the code example. It seems like SelectableText is a very expensive widget. Thus building large numbers of it cripples performance. I have pretty much eliminated the problem by now by wrapping the Text widget in a MouseRegion and rebuilding it as a SelectableText widget when the cursor enters it and rebuilding to a Text widget again when the cursor leaves